# Position splash text or message box

Tags: autohotkey

I am using two monitors and the message boxes always appear in the middle of the primary screen, regardless of where the active window is.
How can I specify the position of a Splash Text box or Message box so that it shows in the middle of the active window, not in the middle of the primary monitor?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#Persistent
AppName=Move
Menu, Tray, Tip, %AppName%
Menu, Tray, Icon , Shell32.dll, 26, 1 ; 45, 28, 113, 74, 134


^w::
WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, A
Mx:=X + (Width/2) -100
My:=Y + (Height/2) -100
SetTimer, MoveMsgBox, -50
MsgBox, ,%AppName%, %X%  %Y% OK
Return

MoveMsgBox:
WinMove, %AppName%, , %Mx% , %My%
Return
```